# Настроить constraint для пропорционального авторесайза uiimageview

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Есть 3 одинаковых `UIImageView` на `ViewController`. Необходимо настроить констреинты так, что бы все 3 `UIImageView` были привязаны ко всем краям с отступом в 20, и отступом между собой в 25. И соответственно пропорционально изменялись в зависимости от размеров экрана.
[image: storyboard]

В итоге получается либо так c aspect ratio 3,3:1 https://monosnap.com/file/DHVulTDPZuKWGqsScSc93zXAlDj3e9

Либо так без указания height https://monosnap.com/file/DSLXdAf7hv8SUmBXJf0XbAUkoAipCW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно поставить констрэйнты "equal heights" (опционально "equal widths") и обычные констрэйнты с `contentView`. Затем, выбираем в сториборде кликаем на каждый констрейнт и задаём отступы в инспекторе в поле "Constant".

[image: Констрэйнты]

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.